# How to do cross-origin requests on IPFS

Tags: cors, cross-domain, ipfs

So I want to put a website on ipfs, but it has some javascript which calls out to a server that is not the ipfs gateway, so I get cross origin errors. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and other headers using `ipfs config`:

```
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Methods '["GET", "POST"]'
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Headers '["Authorization"]'
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Expose-Headers '["Location"]'
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials '["true"]'
```

The values above are just examples; set the real values to what your client code actually needs.

https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-daemon has the (minimal) existing docs on this.

Comment: Ooo this looks promising. So I do this before I do "ipfs add"? Or does this need to be done on the gateway before it is run?

Comment: I *think* you can make changes with `ipfs config` at any time and they take effect without need to restart. But don’t take my word for it…

Comment: I guess what I'm missing is, does the daemon need this or is it the gateway? I realize they can be the same machine, but in the case they aren't.

Comment: The daemon needs it. Or I guess more precisely the API needs it, but it needs to be set by the daemon. The daemon then passes the headers to the API. I guess you can set the daemon to pass them to the gateway but I think you don’t need to

Comment: Ok I'm still getting the CORS errors: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://...../README.md. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. I changed the config on both the gateway and the daemon. Who is the origin? Does the gateway act as a proxy?

Comment: The origin is the scheme+host+port of the server where your JavaScript client code is running. Is that  `https://localhost:8080`? If so, then the API is seeing the right origin at least. But note that setting `API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only allows cross-origin requests to the configured API endpoints, e.g., URLs in the form `http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add` (on whatever scheme+host+port the API is configured to be exposed at).

Comment: If you instead want to make cross-origin requests to the *gateway*, doing `ipfs config --json Gateway.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'` should work. That is, with `Gateway.` instead of `API.` Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Also you might try hardcoding the origin you need, like this: `ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["http:localhost:8080"]'`. The `*` wildcard should work though…

Comment: Also I just did a fresh ipfs install (version 0.4.6) from scratch and I notice that the correct Access-Control-* headers already get set on the gateway by default, without me needing to configure anything…

Comment: The first command worked for me but now I'm getting hit with CORB when I try to view a PDF file that I had uploaded successfully to IPFS :(

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in the answer does not work for me on 2021-03-19.
Fortunately, the [browser-ipns-publish](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-ipns-publish) has an example. The syntax used there is

```
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin "[\"*\"]"
```

Not sure if this is due to being run on Windows but it works-on-mine (TM).